# erro The instance member 'addTime' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

O trecho do código com erro é essa;

```
  void addTime() {
    final addSeconds = 1;
    var seconds = 1;

    setState(() {
      seconds = duration.inSeconds + addSeconds;
      if(seconds < 0){
        timer?.cancel();
      } else {
        duration = 1 as Duration;
        duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
      }
    });
  }
  void starTimer({bool resets = true}) {
   if(!mounted) return;
   if(resets){
     reset();
   }
  }

  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_)  => addTime());
```

Está gerando erro nessa linha;

> timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_)  => addTime());

O erro é esse abaixo

> The instance member 'addTime' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member
> with a different expression

Erro informa que o método addTime precisa ser inicializada, por falta de experiência não consigo corrigir, por favor como posso fazer o método addTime ser inicializada?

Fiz essa tentativa;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TimerWidget extends StatefulWidget  {
  const TimerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TimerWidget> createState() => _TimerWidgetState();
}

class _TimerWidgetState extends State<TimerWidget> {

  Duration duration = Duration();
  late Timer? timer; /* não funcionou*/

  void reset() => setState(() => duration = Duration());

  void addTime() {
    final addSeconds = 1;
    var seconds = 1;

    setState(() {
      seconds = duration.inSeconds + addSeconds;
      if(seconds < 0){
        timer?.cancel();
      } else {
        duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
      }
    });
  }
  void starTimer({bool resets = true}) {
    if(!mounted) return;
    if(resets){
      reset();
    }
  }

  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_)  => addTime());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro, traduzindo livremente, diz que:

> O membro de instância "addTime" não pode ser acessado num inicializador. Tente substituir a referencia para a instância com outra expressão diferente.

Isso ocorre porquê ao definir o objeto, o campo `timer` é gerado. Só que como o objeto como um todo não terminou de ser construído, você não pode referenciar outros campos dele. Isto é: Na inicialização de um objeto, você não pode referenciar diretamente campos do próprio objeto que não são conhecidos em tempo de **compilação**.

Ou seja, você poderia fazer isso se você estivesse tentando referenciar, por exemplo, uma constante:

`String teste = "teste";`

(Ou uma variável estática, por exemplo.)

Para corrigir esse erro, crie um campo e atribua seu valor no construtor da sua classe. Você não incluiu na pergunta o nome da sua classe, no exemplo vou colocar um nome genérico:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    void addTime(){
         //......
    }
    late Timer meuTimer;
    MinhaClasse (){
        meuTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_)  => addTime());
    }
}
```

No exemplo coloquei o modificador `late`. Não tem muito a ver com a pergunta, mas se você quiser, você pode ler mais sobre ele [aqui](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables) (em inglês, e também sobre null-safety como um todo.)

Para maiores informações sobre esse erro, você pode ler [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63542776/10746978) (em inglês).

Se você tem dificuldades com inglês, você pode pesquisar aqui no site mesmo que tem bastante conteúdo sobre isso. Não achando, sugiro criar outra pergunta aqui, desde que bem escrita e dentro do escopo.

Comment: Tentei como você sugeriu, mas não funcionou. Eu atualizei colocando a minha tentativa

Comment: @wladyband Você **não** tentou como eu sugeri. Acredito que você deva reler minha resposta e tentar entender o que propus. 1) Você não criou o construtor. 2) Você deixou a linha antiga que estava dando o erro e criou outra propriedade com o mesmo nome.

Comment: lhe peço mil desculpe, realmente não fui atendo e funcionou, muito obrigado